# How do I take a screenshot of more than my desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, 16.04, screenshot

Whenever I push 'printscreen' or use the screenshot app I capture only my desktop background, see image:

[image]

**Update**

I tried `shutter` as per Andrea's advice. But it does the same thing, only returns the desktop.  However, it outputs some lines on the console that may mean something to someone:

```
org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.compiz was not provided by any .service files

GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1083 was not found when attempting to remove it at /usr/bin/shutter line 7249.
GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 1085 was not found when attempting to remove it at /usr/share/perl5/Shutter/App/ShutterNotification.pm line 186.
```

Comment: I'm curious because I didn't know it was meant to do anything else. What magic were you expecting to do with it?

Comment: I think what he means is the screenshot only shows the desktop background, not the actual content of the screen...

Comment: Is `scrot` working fine?

Comment: @DKBose - I have edited his post.

Comment: What darent said. I can screenshot only my desktop, it doesn't capture the windows on top of it. And what is scrot?

Comment: Does Alt+PrtScr capture the active window, or do the same thing?

Comment: That does nothing at all, unlike printscrn

Comment: WOW!  Interesting that it doesn't capture.  Maybe `gnome-screenshot` needs to be reinstalled.  `sudo apt purge gnome-screenshot` then `sudo apt install gnome-screenshot`.

Comment: I think this is from transparency settings in the programs that are running. Try running shutter from the command line with a delay. That worked when I had a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Richard. It sounds from the the error message that you're having trouble with the compiz module which is responsible for beautifying your desktop environment (http://www.compiz.org/). Perhaps it is some awkward transparency setting that is fooling you. Try to disable compiz and fancy effects it. I don't know where it is located in unity, but it must be somewhere in the settings menu where you set window effects, etc. This should help.

Comment: It's a brand new installation so I can't imagine purging & reinstalling will help much. My guess is now since no one else has had this problem that it's probably VirtualBox at fault, not Ubuntu. Their graphics drivers never seem to work perfectly.

Comment: I guess I should have paid attention.  Pressing PrtScr while in virtualbox, takes a desktop pic, not of virtualbox.  It should be your entire desktop including your virtualbox screen as well.  When I wanted only what was in the virtualbox, I had to open a terminal in virtualbox and run `gnome-snapshot` from the command line to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

I use shutter:

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

you can then select:

1. Desktop -> Capture all workspaces
2. Selection
3. window, context menu, etc.